# Override 3party widget Templates in TYPO3

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-9.x

I have an Extension and i want to override the widget templates. For Paginate ViewHelper looks like this:

`widget.TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\ViewHelpers\Widget\PaginateViewHelper.templateRootPath = Path to templates`

But how is it for 3party Extensions? (TYPO3 9.5)

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're searching for is something like this:

```
plugin.tx_foobar {
  view {
    widget {
      TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\ViewHelpers\Widget\PaginateViewHelper {
        templateRootPath = {$plugin.tx_foobar.view.templateRootPath}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: No. Thats for paginate Viewhelper, which i wrote as Example. Thanks anyways

Comment: It's the same schema: `<VendorName>\<ExtensionName\>ViewHelpers\Widget\<WidgetViewHelper>`